CSSH (ClusterSSH) installation on Linux (Rhel 9)
I am trying to install CSSH on RHEL9 in WSL, I tried below and getting error. Any Ideas
[root@aaa rhel9]# dnf install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:17:23 ago on Sat 14 Dec 2024 09:39:03 PM NZDT.
epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                             16 kB/s |  19 kB     00:01
Package epel-release-9-9.el9.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

[root@aaa rhel9]# dnf install -y clusterssh
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:17:39 ago on Sat 14 Dec 2024 09:39:03 PM NZDT.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides perl(Exception::Class) >= 1.31 needed by clusterssh-4.18-1.el9.noarch from epel
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

I tried these
dnf install -y perl-CPAN
cpan -i Exception::Class

Should I use these flags? Or try to avoid?
dnf install -y clusterssh --skip-broken
dnf install -y clusterssh --nobest

Exception::Class is already installed
root@aaa rhel9]# perl -MCPAN -e shell Terminal does not support AddHistory. To fix that, maybe try> install Term::ReadLine::Perl cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.29) Enter 'h' for help. 

cpan[2]> install Exception::Class Exception::Class is up to date (1.45). 

Kind of running out of Ideas...
REF:
Using cssh with an ssh clone
clusterssh with multiple monitor
https://infotechys.com/install-cluster-ssh-on-linux/
https://www.putorius.net/cluster-ssh.html#centos-red-hat-installation-of-cluster-ssh
How to install ClusterSSH (cssh) on CentOS?

If you're installing EPEL packages on RHEL9, you need to enable the Code Ready Builder repository. If you have a license for RHEL9, then you can enable it via subscription-manager:
$ sudo subscription-manager repos \
  --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-9-$(rpm -E "%{_arch}")-rpms

Otherwise, you can drop the following into /etc/yum.repos.d/crb.repo:
[centos-crb]
name=CentOS 9 CRB - $basearch
baseurl=https://mirror.stream.centos.org/9-stream/CRB/x86_64/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Official-SHA256

With both EPEL and CRB enabled, I am able to successfully install the clusterssh package on RHEL 9.

Responding to other parts of your question:

I tried these
dnf install -y perl-CPAN
cpan -i Exception::Class


Installing something outside of the package system (i.e., without using rpm or yum/dnf) doesn't do you any good -- the package system doesn't know the dependency is available. While you could, in theory, download the clusterssh package file and then install it using rpm -i --nodeps, you end up with a system that has a broken dependency tree. Better to solve the actual problem rather than trying to hack around it.

Should I use these flags? Or try to avoid?
dnf install -y clusterssh --skip-broken
dnf install -y clusterssh --nobest


Neither of these options will permit you to install a package that has a missing dependency. The --skip-broken option will remove uninstallable packages from a transaction set. That means if you were to do something like dnf install packageA packageB packageC, and packageC had missing dependencies, the command would still successfully install packageA and packageB (without --skip-broken the command would fail and install no packages). Compare the behavior of:
yum -y install make clusterssh

With:
yum -y install make clusterssh --skip-broken

The first command fails (Error: Unable to find a match: clusterssh). The second command successfully installs make.
The --nobest option allows dnf to install an older version of a package, which may allow some transactions to complete successfully even if the latest version of a package has unmet dependencies.

Side note: how did I discover the solution? I performed a google search for perl-exception-class rpm, which brought me here, which got me looking into "what the heck is the the CentOS CRB repository?", which brought me to the document to which I linked in the first paragraph.
